# Capacitance multiplier or parallel capacitors for ultralow noise power supply

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, linear

For a linear power supply after the bridge rectifier stage, what is the best way to filter the output power?

- Is it possible to use typical capacitance multiplier circuit with a power BJT or MOSFET, or should I use normal high capacitance capacitors in parallel?
- What are the benefits and use case for either of these?
- Why should I choose one over the other?

Comment: Exactly how low noise is ultralow noise? Give us some target figures. 10 nV/√Hz? 1 nV/√Hz? 100 nV/√Hz?

Comment: Best way, for what use case? How much current? And do you really mean noise, or do you just mean ripple?

Comment: @Justme I mean for both ripple and noise. 3A continuous current. And maybe 1uV RMS ripple?

Comment: capacitance multipliers do not reduce noise, they only reduce ripple.

Comment: @tobalt Capacitance multipliers are great for reducing noise. With a BJT, you can get down to the emitter noise level, usually very low.

Comment: @JohnDoty but only if the noise is already low on the cap, so that means the transistor does not improve noise. In fact, as you say, the transistor adds its own (low) noise level. Without a transistor you can reach noise only limited by the capacitor ESR.

Comment: I recently designed a charge sense amplifier for a nuclear particle detector, powered from USB. USB bricks can be pretty noisy and ripply. I used a capacitance multiplier to kill the noise and ripple. I don't know quantitatively how well it worked, because the CSA noise wound up so low that the downstream multichannel analyzer's input noise dominated.

Comment: @tobalt But in a capacitance multiplier, you have a pretty large bias resistor between the input and the cap, making a nice low-pass filter. That's more effective than simply putting the cap across the power supply output. The filter doesn't care about your distinction between ripple and noise.

Comment: @JohnDoty ok let me put it in other terms: the output noise of the Cap. Multiplier *is not lower* than noise at the input RC filter. In fact, it is slightly higher than at the input RC node. It lowers HF noise but adds LF noise due to the large R, which leaves the **RMS noise the same** as at the input RC node.

Comment: @tobalt I have no idea what you mean by "input RC filter".  The fact is that the cap multiplier is effective at reducing noise and ripple, especially at high frequencies. Take the output of a crappy power brick, run it though a cap multiplier filter, get much quieter power.

Answer (score 7):

You need a reservoir capacitor to store energy  between pulses from the rectifier.

A capacitance multiplier is a type of series regulator it does not store (much) energy.

There's no reason why you can't use both,  a reservoir capacitor to store energy followed by a capacitance multiplier to chop the peaks off the ripple, allowing a low-ripple output without sacrificing too much power factor by using an oversized reservoir capacitor.

Comment: I like the way this is couched, despite being short. Says a lot, tersely. +1.

Comment: Good post that emphasizes the right things, namely that it is sort of a series regulator and doesn't store energy and thus works against ripple (turning it into **heat**) but **does not reduce noise**. It buffers the potential (incl. noise) of the input RC. To reduce this noise, only a larger C is effective.

Comment: But then why would you use a capacitance multiplier instead of an actual regulator, which has effectively infinite capacitance?

Comment: @tobalt what's the difference between ripple and noise?

Comment: @user253751 capacitive multiplier has a reduced headroom requirement versus LM7805, and even LDO regulators.  etc

Comment: @Jasen ripple is a consequence of the load current that drains the output voltage while the energy input is intermittent. no load current -> no ripple. a low output impedance thus helps against ripple. this "Cap Multiplier" is RC + a transistor buffer for low output impedance. noise originates from all other circuitry and present regardless of loading. The RMS noise here depends only on C.

Comment: That said, it can still *appear* like the capacitance multiplier reduces noise because: It shifts the dominant noise spectrum to low frequencies due to the RC lowpass. As opamps and gain stages often have much better PSRR at low frequencies, the end result can be quieter, although the power rail has essentially the same (or slightly larger) RMS noise as without the Cap Multiplier

Comment: @Jasen But I mean, why not take a capacitance multiplier, and replace the capacitor with a voltage reference? And now you have a voltage regulator.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment about a bridge rectifier, I’m assuming you’re talking about AC to DC conversion.

> what is the best way to filter the output power?

This depends on the application and requirements. There’s usually a trade off between physical space, efficiency, and output ripple. The type of load may affect how much capacitance you can have on the output as well.

> Is it possible to use typical capacitance multiplier circuit with a power BJT or MosFET?

Not only is this possible but it’s fairly common for low noise applications. It’s more common to use a dual capacitance multiplier however which allows you to control the capacitance without relying heavily on the gain of the transistor which is device dependent.

> or should I use normal high capacitance capacitors in parallel?

This depends on your requirements

> What are the benefits and use case for either of these? And why should I choose one over the other?

The capacitance multiplier is typically used in very low noise situations where the amount of capacitance needed is impractical to accomplish directly. Some reasons not to use it however are

1. If you don’t need really low noise, you may end up using more space with a capacitance multiplier than just using parallel capacitors.
2. The transistors are going to dissipate some of the power, so you will lose efficiency.
3. The capacitance multiplier is more complicated which introduces some risk that may be unnecessary if you can meet your requirements with just capacitors.

Comment: Hey Ryan, The use case is for a power supply. So, after the transformer to the bridge rectifier stage and then comes the DC filter stage. I am aiming to achieve very low noise and ripple for the psu.

Is it possible for you to explain the number 2 reason further more? Like what type of power loss will I have? And also any formula to calculate the power loss through the pass transistor? Also, do you have suggestions for the pass transistor to use for 24V@7A?

Also, for the number 3 point, what are the other risks you think it has and also why is it complicated if I am using a power BJT/FET,

Comment: Hi Roger, this sounds like a fun project. If you need help with a specific design, we will need to know as much specific information about the design as you can give us. Do you have a noise requirement, or can you tell us what the power supply will be used for? The power loss in the transistor is essentially the diode drop times the collector current (V_CE * I_C). A capacitance multiplier is a more complex circuit than a few capacitors. It’s easier to get it wrong, hence more risk.

Comment: the overall specifications are a little vague because I am trying to build a bench precision low noise power supply to test all of my future projects. I will be working with Radio equipment and also normal microcontroller based automation stuff. I am going forward through the design step by step starting from the mains input and transformer and then slowly going towards the regulated output. Trying to figure out each module individually.

Comment: Right now I am trying to figure out the bridge rectifier and secondary filtering stage after the transformer. Also, I was wondering if I should use a single or double fuse after the transformer's secondary winding and then build up the rectifier and filter section. But then for the fuse, I have to take account of the filter capacitors inrush current. Also. I am planning to build 3 galvanic isolated channels. So, I should start the isolation from the bridge rectifier stage isn't it? Like right after the transformer secondary AC output? Also, the ripple I am trying to go for is 1uV RMS.

Comment: Just want to implement all the best possible design practices and requirements while building this project and the lowest possible ripple I can get at a reasonable size and also reasonable for the use case. Low voltage and current Radio testing and also low level microcontroller stuff.